# Module has not been deployed

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, tomcat8

I am trying to create a web service in a web application on netbeans 8.2 (server-tomcat 8.0.27.0) which can connect to a database on postgres and read a table named "test". i have this code in download.java (web service in a package called serve)

**Download.java**

```
@WebService(serviceName = "download")
public class Download {

    Connection con=null;    

    private DataSource getJdbcPostgres() throws NamingException, SQLException {
        Context c = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds=(DataSource) c.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres");
        con=ds.getConnection();
        return ds;
   }

   @WebMethod(operationName = "download")
   public String download(@WebParam(name = "username")String username, @WebParam(name = "id")String id) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

       String sql = "select * from test where id="+id;
       Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
       PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
       ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
       ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();
       rs.next();
       return "";
   } 

}
```

here's my context.xml file (in META-INF)

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/service2">
 <Resource name="jdbc/postgres" auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
      url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
      username="someusername" password="somepassword" maxTotal="20" maxIdle="10"
      maxWaitMillis="-1"/>
 </Context>
```

and here's web.xml (in WEB-INF):

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
   <listener>
       <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>download</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>download</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/download</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <session-config>
       <session-timeout>
           30
       </session-timeout>
   </session-config>
   <resource-ref>
       <description>postgreSQL Datasource example</description>
       <res-ref-name>jdbc/postgres</res-ref-name>
       <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
       <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
   </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

clean and build command is successful but it doesn't deploy on apache tomcat server
error message (output when I tried to deploy it):

```
Checking data source definitions for missing JDBC drivers...
Undeploying ...
undeploy?path=/service2
OK - Undeployed application at context path /service2
In-place deployment at D:\NetBeansProjects\service2\build\web
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FTRAINE%7E3%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext1366288511044657094.xml&path=/service2
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /service2 but context failed to start
D:\NetBeansProjects\service2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1094: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

when i tried to change server to GlassFish 4.1.1, it says:

```
Severe:   WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: 
com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: 
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of 
IllegalAnnotationExceptions
javax.xml.transform.SourceLocator is an interface, and JAXB can't handle 
interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at javax.xml.transform.SourceLocator
        at public javax.xml.transform.SourceLocator 
     serve.jaxws.TransformerConfigurationExceptionBean.locator
        at serve.jaxws.TransformerConfigurationExceptionBean
Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: 
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of 
IllegalAnnotationExceptions
javax.xml.transform.SourceLocator is an interface, and JAXB can't handle 
interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at javax.xml.transform.SourceLocator
        at public javax.xml.transform.SourceLocator 
serve.jaxws.TransformerConfigurationExceptionBean.locator
        at serve.jaxws.TransformerConfigurationExceptionBean
Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /service2
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: javax.servlet.ServletException: 
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to 
parse runtime descriptor: com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: 
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of 
IllegalAnnotationExceptions
javax.xml.transform.SourceLocator is an interface, and JAXB can't handle 
interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at javax.xml.transform.SourceLocator
        at public javax.xml.transform.SourceLocator serve.jaxws.TransformerConfigurationExceptionBean.locator
        at serve.jaxws.TransformerConfigurationExceptionBean
```

I am a newcomer to this field so plz help me if im wrong somewhere or missing something!

Comment: Please consider using uppercase class names :) (such as `Download.java` and `public class Download`)

Comment: I tried...result is the same

Comment: I think he meant using uppercase class names is simply a norm almost everybody follows, which is why you should use it. It won't fix your problem, but will make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it happened but I just put try-catch instead of throws and it is getting deployed!

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "download")
public String download(@WebParam(name = "username")String username, @WebParam(name = "id")String id) {
try {
        String sql="select * from test";
        Connection conn=myDatasource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(connect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
return "someString";
}
```

Can anyone suggest why didn't it work earlier? Although my problem is solved yet I'm curious to know what was wrong with 'throws Exception'!
P.S. I'm running it on GlassFish 4.1.1 this time